# C# Xamarin How to update a static string in a label

Tags: c#, xamarin, binding, static, cross-platform

i want to update a label with a static string. 
Thats my actual Code

```
public partial class MainPage : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private static String _uploadstring;
    /// <summary>
    /// A static property which you'd like to bind to
    /// </summary>
    public static String Uploadstring
    {
        get
        {
            return _uploadstring;
        }

        set
        {
            _uploadstring = value;

        }
    }
```

and i want call it with

```
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            Uploadstring = "TEEEEEEST";
        });
```

here is my XAML Binding

```
       <Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Staticlocal:MainPage.UploadString}}" x:Name="ttts"  TextColor="Red" TranslationY="50" HeightRequest="30" FontSize="26" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
```

If i set i breakpoint i see that the Uploadstring is updated in my XAML. But he dont display it because he dosent update the text. How can i solve my problem?

Comment: Where you set OnPropertyChanged event with your key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about insert one line on Setter?

```
public static String Uploadstring
{
    get
    {
        return _uploadstring;
    }
    set
    {
        _uploadstring = value;
        Form.ttts.Text = _uploadstring;  // This line (Modified)
    }
}
```

if you don't like to use like this, you need to bind it with Twoway Mode

**Added**

Add this for using static method

```
    public static MainPage Form { get; set; } // This Line

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form = this; // And This Line
    }
```